# Vector problem regarding a quadrilateral

Tags: vectors

say we have a quadrilateral $ABCD$ and a point $O$. Lets construct four points which are symmetric to $O$ about the midpoints of the sides of $ABCD$. What kind of quadrilateral do we get with these four points? Here is my picture

[image]

Basically, we are trying to show what kind of quadrilateral is $A_1B_1C_1D_1$. My guess is that it is parallelogram? IS it enough to prove that $\vec{A_1 B_1} = \vec{ D_1 C_1} $ ??

Comment: No, it's not. Either you prove also the other pair of opposite sides is parallel or else you show $\;|A_1B_1|=|D_1C_1|\;$ after showing parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is sufficient to show that $$\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}=\overrightarrow{D_1C_1}$$ since this implies that they are parallel and of equal length.
This can easily be seen if you let $$\overrightarrow{OA}=\underline{a}$$ and likewise for the other vertices of the quadrilateral, whereupon $$\overrightarrow{OA_1}=\underline{a}+\underline{b}$$, and similarly in cyclic order for the other vertices of the quadrilateral in question, and thus $$\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}=\underline{c}-\underline{a}=\overrightarrow{D_1C_1}$$

Comment: I think OP misses one case. What if O lies outside the quadrilateral??

Comment: @user135395 I don't see it makes any difference

Comment: Why? I mean it would be a different shape